# How can Word put footnotes in two columns only all the text fits on one line?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm yearning for Footnote 3 to be right of, and on the same line, as 2.

[image]

But when I chose '2 column', Word didn't do what I yearned! It split Footnote 1.

[image]

### Update : Gregg's answer dated 2020 Feb 7 doesn't work.

As you can see below, 'Columns' is faded and can't be picked.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't Word putting in 2 columns footnotes that can doubtless fit on 1 line?](https://superuser.com/questions/1516744/why-isnt-word-putting-in-2-columns-footnotes-that-can-doubtless-fit-on-1-line)

Comment: @music2myear No. Question differs.

Answer (score 1):

Footnotes are generated automatically in Word, as a tradeoff, you don't have full control on its formatting.

With proper footnotes you can't get the behaviour you look for (also I don't think it'd be the desired behaviour for others as it makes reading more difficult)

You can create list of footnotes manually which look like you need it, but you'll need to keep it up to date manually.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Word 2016 & Office 365 v1908 (Build 11929.20606 Click-to-Run):

1. Select/move cursor near footnote numbers (at top/citation spot)
2. Layout, Columns, 2

   [image]
3. Near the bottom footnotes themselves, click at the END of the sentence/wording of one (in this case footnote 2)
4. Hit Enter as many times as you need to add whitespace to force the next footnote (#3) to the new column to align it to existing footnote (#2)

This affects all footnotes, meaning you can't simply make footnote 2 & 3 on the same line, it'll likely adjust more footnotes. Not sure if you can do anymore than that, but here are some other options to explore: Endnotes, citations, link to footer (put 1 near text, superscript it, insert hyperlink from it to another spot in document)

**--EDIT**
It does appear my suggestion adds columns to the WHOLE document instead of just the footnotes. I'm not sure this CAN be done. I'd return the points if I could, I believe they were awarded since I was the only answer when bounty expired.

Comment: Hi! Please re-reread my post that I now edited. Your step 2 doesn't work.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I don't think it will help you sadly :(