# What program might've been footnoted different number of footnotes per line?

Tags: footnote

Oxford University Press (OUP) publishes the following books, and couldn't have used Microsoft Word to variate the number of footnotes per line, because [harrymc](https://superuser.com/a/1520058) affirmed

> I have done some tests on Word 2019, and it seems that the option of "Footnote layout" is now dead and non-functional. [. . .] Your only option is to file a bug-report to Microsoft using the Feedback Hub, then wait for a fix.

So what programs might've OUP used? I emailed them, but they're on summer vacation.
The first screenshot is from[*Criminal Law: Text, Cases, and Materials* (8 edn, 2018)](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/criminal-law-9780198811817?cc=ca&lang=en&). p 180.

[image]

Same with [*Anson's Law of Contract* (31 edn 2020)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198829973) p 180.

[image]

Comment: Please could you clarify your question?

Comment: @Attie Sorry! Done! Clear now?

Comment: Why do you get the idea that they are using an off-the-shelf product?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 What do you mean? I eliminated only Microsoft Word, not any other program.

Comment: You clearly ask, “So what programs might've OUP used?” When my contention is this could have been handled manually in layout after the fact.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Ah! Sorry. I'm afraid my mind blocked that grueling possibility!